# How to auto generate Rails REST API documentation for controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, documentation

How to automatically generate API documentation for Rails REST controller?

Is there any example I can look into using RDoc to do this?

Answer (score 34):

You can try `apipie-rails` which I created: https://github.com/Pajk/apipie-rails/

It can do more things than just generate documentation, more info on https://github.com/Pajk/apipie-rails/.

Comment: The first question I had when I looked at this was if the use of the DSL unnecessarily bloats to rails app at runtime. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada You can generate a cache and turn of parameters validation for production mode. It is mentioned here https://github.com/Pajk/apipie-rails#static-files

Comment: has apipie rails been abandoned? there is a bunch of pull requests with no answer?

Comment: No, it has not, although I admin not being the best project maintainer in the world, the level of contribution and interest is growing steady, as well as new features and bug fixes

Answer (score 5):

I found https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation to be a really nice tool. It's driven off of rspec acceptance tests so you're writing documentation at the same time you're writing acceptance tests!  Double win!

Answer (score 2):

Use [rapi_doc](http://rubygems.org/gems/rapi_doc) gem. The setup is very simple and straight forward. Follow this tutorial: http://www.rubyglob.com/generating-api-documentation-with-rapi_doc/

Comment: Lack of docs and tests make this hard to use.

Comment: This seems out of date and doesn't run with Rails 4.

Comment: website is 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "calamum" a ruby build program to generate a nice html api doc from yaml file definition.
https://github.com/malachheb/calamum

Answer (score 0):

Although is not *automatic*, I define and document my APIs using RESTful API Modeling Language or, [RAML](http://raml.org).

There are Node.js packages that turn the yaml file into a nice looking html documentation, like [raml2html](https://github.com/kevinrenskers/raml2html).

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for a good documentation tool which can be easily integrated into rails. Finally we built our own rails engine [APIDOCO](https://github.com/72pulses/apidoco)

However it does not auto generate the documentation but you can easily use it.